# How does Superman fasten his cape to his costume?

Tags: dc, superman, costume

I was checking out the *[arms at his sides](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnbVd.jpg)* image included in [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/24910/why-does-superman-put-one-or-both-arms-up-when-he-flies) and it made me wonder how Superman's cape is attached to his costume. His cape just disappears into his collar. While his muscles are well defined and can be seen through his skin tight uniform, the capes out line below Superman's collar is non existant. Is there a canon answer? How does Superman fasten his cape to his costume? (I'm really hoping for an image that shows how it is worn.)

Comment: Looks to me like it's sewn onto the rim of his collar....

Comment: It *could* be, but after 80 or so years, there ought to be at least one comic panel or live action sequence that shows how it is affixed.

Comment: When he removes the costume, the cape is still attached. This would explain why you don't see it being attached separately. Much like you never see him "pinning" his superman emblem onto his chest after donning the tights.

Comment: Jim Croce said "you don't tug on Superman's cape". Now I wonder if Supes has an anger management issue, or if he's afraid of a wardrobe malfunction.

Comment: If it was Chuck norris's cape it would stay on for fear of an butt kicking.

Comment: Why, he uses Super-Glue, of course.

Comment: Because he told it too stay on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cape is detachable; there are hooks just inside the collar that the cape attaches to.  I do not recall ever seeing an image of these hooks, but I do recall it being discussed in both comics and Maggin's novelizations.

Answer (score 10):

This was addressed in [Superman #282](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Superman_Vol_1_282). The cape attaches to the shirt piece by two hooks.

[image]